# How to hang up a call automatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, phone-call

I'm very interesting to know how to hang up a call automatically. If I push my call button

(this is it's code):

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phone.text]];
}
```

I want to hang up the call after 5 seconds automatically. How can I do that?.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that you are able to interrupt user's call from your app.

Comment: Just cause I'm curious: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You can place calls from your app, not hang them up.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It would be nice to have a callback or event on stupid spam calls with a regex of a certain number than hang up on the call.

Comment: callkit might add some options for this...

Answer (score 3):

That is outside the scope of the iOS SDK. You can't tell the phone subsystem to do anything. This merely invokes the system to do something.

Answer (score 1):

you can't, you can initiate call from your app but you can't hang up.